# Prove that function $f: \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \to \mathcal P(\mathbb N), f(\varphi)=\varphi(\mathbb N)$ is surjective

Tags: functions

$\varphi$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.
I guess I need to assume f is not surjective and then get a cotradiction, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It seems false to me.

Comment: Well $\varphi(\mathbb{N})$ will never equal the empty set. However, all other sets can be constructed, you do not need a proof by contradiction.

Comment: What is $f$? Does it map characteristic functions to their sets? If that's the case, there's your surjection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ denotes the power set. Then $\emptyset \notin f(\mathbb N^{\mathbb N})$. All other $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ are in the image of $f$. Choose any $a \in A$ and define $\varphi$ by  $\varphi(n) = a$ for $n \notin A$ and $\varphi(n) = n$ for $n \in A$. Then $f(\varphi) = A$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As others note, it is not true since $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ but has no pre-image under $f$. However the following proof replaces $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ by $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$

To prove $f$ is surjective, take an arbitrary element of its range, and find an element in the domain which $f$ maps to it. In this case, the range of $f$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, so let $S\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ be an arbitrary non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

An element of the domain will be a function $\phi$, and $f(\phi)=\phi(\mathbb{N})$ means that $f$ returns the range of $\phi$. So we must construct a function $\phi$ whose range is the set $S$.

Since $\mathbb N$ is countable, so is $S$, so we can enumerate the elements of $S$:

$$S=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots\}$$

Then for the function $\phi$, take $\phi(1)=s_1$, $\phi(2)=s_2$, $\phi(3)=s_3$, and so on. Thus, the range of $\phi$ is $S$, i.e. $f(\phi)=S$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite true. If the codomain had be $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}) \setminus \{ \emptyset \}$, then I'd agree it's surjective. Note that a function $\varphi$ from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{N}$ must map (say) $1$ to a number in $\Bbb{N}$, hence $\varphi(1) \in \varphi(\Bbb{N}) \neq \emptyset$.

Otherwise, every subset $S$ of $\Bbb{N}$ is equal to $\varphi(\Bbb{N})$ for some $\varphi: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$. All you do is pick on one special point $m \in S$, and define
$$\varphi_{S, m}(n) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } n \in S \\ m & \text{if }n \notin S \end{cases}.$$
Then $\varphi_{S, m}(\Bbb{N}) = S$ as required.